# LUKS overwrite empty disk space question

Tags: encryption, luks

I have a question about LUKS and the overwrite empty disk space option. I know what it does, and why people use it but I have a question about it. Forgive me if this question is dumb, it's just something that popped in my head at what point and thought I'd ask. When you check this option, does it overwrite the empty disk space just once at the installation process? Or does it perform this procedure everytime you boot up and shut down your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option isn't part of LUKS itself, it sounds like it's part of whatever installer you're using. It would happen just once when installing in order to delete any data on the disk to make sure none of the old data could be recovered.